# Typescript installation issue: 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: typescript, installation

I have successfully installed node and npm. I am having issue with installation of type script.

```
C:\Users\rajan>npm --version
7.24.0

C:\Users\rajan>node --version
v16.10.0

C:\Users\rajan>npm install --location=global typescript@4.6.4

up to date, audited 2 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\rajan>tsc --version
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\rajan>
```

It saying 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. what is causing this issue...How to proceed???